# How to force to load 32bit dependencies?

Tags: 64-bit, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I had application, that was made in 32 bit system.

Now, I have 64bit, and the app automatically switched to load 64 bit dependencies...  (and it crashes in 64bit OS).

[image]

however, how to force it to load not from `Wow64`, but from `system32`?

Answer (score 1):

> How to force it to load not from Wow64, but from system32?

`WoW64` *is the way* to call 32-bit LIBs/APPs from a 64-bit system. I quote from [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64):

> In computing on Microsoft platforms, WoW64 (Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit) is a subsystem of the Windows operating system capable of running 32-bit applications that is included in all 64-bit versions of Windows[...]

So WoW64 accesses the 32-bit `system32` LIBs *by design*, because that's its sole reason to exist.

Comment: @T.Todua: WoW64 can be considered somewhat as a gateway from 64-bit to 32-bit. I hope that does help.